# Using a standard OLS linear regression or a panel model for small sample size

Tags: regression, least-squares, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have created a dataset involving certain NLP variables for news-websites over time.
The data involves six news-websites which are observed over 27 time periods with some missing data.

As I only have six news-websites in my dataset I am unsure whether I should be using a standard OLS regression or run a fixed / random effect model.

Currently, I am running some fixed models which yield acceptable results but the R. I am using 14 to 20 independent variables which means that I am not able to run a random-effects model to compare my results too.
So does it make more sense in this situation to use a standard linear model?
But the normal linear models seem to result in un normally high R squared (80+) and with nearly all variables significant which seem weird.
I am fairly new to this so please point out when there are parts missing in this question.

Comment: You need to give much more context for this to be answerable. Sample size? What is the purpose of the model? What are those variables measuring? ...